# HTTP to HTTPS: Express & Heroku

Tags: reactjs, express, http, heroku, https

Heroku suggests to use NPM packages to handle forcing SSL for express apps. I've tried about a dozen without success. The only thing I can get to work is shown below but then Google gets mad.

**Question: Can someone please tell me a working method as of 2022 to force HTTPS on an express app?**

```
<script>
//This works but Google Console gets angry: Page indexing issues: Page with redirect

var host = "www.URL.com" || "URL.com";
if ((host == window.location.host) && (window.location.protocol != "https:")){
window.location.protocol = "https";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the [`Strict-Transport-Security`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security) header, the browser will remember that this is an HTTPS only site *after accessing it over HTTPS for the first time*. The browser then substitutes every subsequent request to `http://your.server` with a request to `https://your.server`, so it will never again visit your site over HTTP.

To ensure that a first visit over HTTPS happens, add a permanent redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. (I don't think this redirect should upset Google, for example, `github.com` does it in the same way.)

The following code assumes that Heroku runs the app on both HTTP and HTTPS for you.

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (!(req.client instanceof tls.TLSSocket))
    return res.redirect(301, "https://your.server");
  res.set("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=86400");
  next();
});
```